# getting trouble to generate sonar test report

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonarqube on my windows server, and it is working find from my client PCs, now I need to generation sonar test report in form of file, pdf, html or in any format to display it to my client. I tried but am not getting any solution, would you please help me, that how to export sonar test report from sonarqube server.

Answer (score 0):

You're not finding that "report export" feature because SonarQube is about continually monitoring the evolution of your code, not printing out a point in time and pinning it to the wall.

If you *really* have to have something like this, then screenshots are the easiest way to go. Alternately, you can pull current state data using web services and build your own report.

Comment: is there any other ways to produce sonar test analysis report  ?